# R/shiny read write text as verbatim

Tags: r, shiny

Does anyone happen to know how to read and write a text file verbatim?  I would like to treat the text as just text and not any sort of data.  The text file is just passage of an essay. I've tried readline, readLines, scan, print, print.noquote, etc using various options to no avail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that might be a hold up:

1) Make sure you have your working directory set to where the .txt file is located. You can use `getwd()` and `setwd()` to do this.

2) Once the directory is set, I usually do something like:

```
file<-list.files(*.txt) 
# * is a wildcard, you could also just put the name of the file here.
```

then

```
readLines(file)
```

should get you what you need.